# Comparing two integral variables cast to object?

Tags: c#, .net

Say that I have an class that has a property named value of type object. That property will get assigned integral whole types,  short, uint, int32, int64 etc.

Is there some performant way to do comparisons on that property, like obj1.Value > obj2.Value?

Naturally this will generate an error, I guess I could do a method with logic like

```
 if (value1 is Int64 && value2 is Int32)
  { 
     return  (Int64) value1 >   (Int32) value2; 
  }
  else if (value1 is Int32 && value2 is Int64)
  { 
     return  (Int32) value1 >   (Int64) value2; 
  }
```

etc etc for all combinations, but it seems rather cludgy :) I'd rather not use reflection nor dynamic for performance reasons. Basically what I want is polymorphic operands

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
return  ( Convert.ToInt64(value1) > Convert.ToInt64(value1) );
```

which is equivalent to

```
return ((IConvertible)value1).ToInt64(null) > ((IConvertible)value2).ToInt64(null);
```

Comment: that might be a good solution, but won't conversion that way allocate memory for two new variables, if you do alot of comparisons you'd thrash the memory no?

Comment: @mko - I don't much like the string creation either.

Comment: I don't see why it's needed, think he added it for some reason :)

Comment: @mko yes you can skip the ToString() part :)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert each value to a `double`.

```
return Convert.ToDouble(value1) > Convert.ToDouble(value2);
```